# Changing CSS properties after a successful Google login using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently wrote a website using HTML and it uses Google's OAuth. After a successful login, a script written in JavaScript using jQuery is supposed to hide sections with a class of "login" and display sections with class of "login_success". Sadly after a successful login everything is getting displayed which makes the website look really messy.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>A test website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="token">
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="site-header clearfix">
 <nav>
  <div class="logo" id="top">
   <h1><a href="#top"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo_image"></a></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu login">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#download">Download</a></li>
    <li><button class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn">Login</button></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu login_success">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Blogs</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Anouncments</a></li>
     <li><a href="#download">Admin</a></li>
     <li><button onclick="signOut()">Sign out</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>

<section class="login_success">
  <div class="data">
    <img id="profile_picture"/>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h1 id="name"></h1>
    <p>Email adress:</p>
    <p id="email"></p>
  </div>
</section>

 <section class="login">
  <div class="leftside">
   <img src="images/preview1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
   <h1>Some header text</h1>
   <p>Some more text...</p>
   <button onclick="window.location.href='#info'">Click me!</button>
  </div>
 </section>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css for class "login" and "login success":

```css
.login{
  display: run-in;
}
.login_success{
  display: none;
}
```

Here is the login.js file:

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile=googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  $(".login").css("display","none");
  $(".login_success").css("display", "run-in");
  $("#profile_picture").attr("src",profile.getImageUrl());
  $("#email").text(profile.getEmail());
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `display: run-in` is only available in IE and no modern browsers? https://caniuse.com/#feat=run-in

Comment: Where is `onSignIn()` called?

Comment: Protip: If you want to be taken seriously as a professional, take those red squiggly lines that show your spelling errors seriously.

Comment: @Turnip thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @isherwood it's getting called after a successful login via Google.  (line 23 in HTML)

Comment: So anyway, I got it to work by changing the display property for login class to "flex" and login_sucess to "block". Sadly it only works on Chrome, on other browsers I get an error with code 400 redirect_uri_mismatch. Why is it working on Chrome and not on other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing was that instead of using `display: run-in;` for the `login` and `login_success` class I should have used `display: flex;`.

But this only seems to work on Chrome, on other browsers I get `Error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch` but that's probably for another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Google's log-in API already has handlers set up

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

The "Additional Capabilities" section has what you need.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable here. Please include the relevant information in your answer.